# C/MPI: Gather matrix blocks by rows

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a C program that reads a 4x4 matrix from a file in a parallel way and distributes it in a block-cyclic way, so that, for 4 processes, it is split among them in 2x2 grids:

```
   /--------------- proc. 0
|00 01|02 03|------ proc. 1
|10 11|12 13|
|-----|-----|
|20 21|22 23|
|30 31|32 33|------ proc. 3
   \--------------- proc. 2
```

... then does some operation on it (multiplication with other matrices), it works like a charm.

The problem comes when, afterwards, I want the resulting blocks to be put together into a result matrix, but **by rows**.

Currently I am trying to do this via MPI_Gather, as follows:

```
MPI_Gather(local,  4,    MPI_FLOAT, // send
           global, size, MPI_FLOAT, // recv
           0, comm);
```

but the data gathered into the buffer are placed as blocks, like that:

```
|00 01 10 11|02 03 12 13|20 21 30 31|22 23 32 33|
```

... while I want them to be distributed "by rows", like:

```
|00 01 02 03|10 11 12 13|20 21 22 23|30 31 32 33|
```

I think I have to do it with some MPI `Datatype`, like contiguous, subarray or similars (I'd also prefer that, it's more elegant that using MPI_Gatherv with floats). But I'm trying without getting some result at the moment.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot avoid using a data type (subarray is the best fit) and MPI_Gatherv()